# In the Middle of a Long Rectangular Slab I Lay

Tags: riddle

> In the middle of a long rectangular slab I sleep and lay
>
> I am Round, Straight, or Curved, you could say
>
> I cannot run forward/backward, but I sometimes can spin
>
> And when I refuse to do so, I get poked with something thin
>
> I live on a flat desert, close to the border
>
> I require no food, no water, no order.

**What am I?**

*I apologize for the cringy rhymes :)*

Comment: As a couch potato, I'd almost say "me" was the answer for the first few lines... but I balked at the "require no food" part.

Comment: @Phylyp LOLOL That's got to be the best joke I've heard in a longgg time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you a:

> Door handle

In the middle of a long rectangular slab I sleep and lay

> Doors are long and rectangular

I am Round, Straight, or Curved, you could say

> Door handles come in many different shapes

I cannot run forward/backward, but I sometimes can spin

> Some rotate as their action for opening the door

And when I refuse to do so, I get poked with something thin

> If you can't open the door, you put something thin in it (like a key, or in a hotel, a card)

I live on a flat desert, close to the border

> Doors are usually flat, and the handle is usually close to the jamb (border)

I require no food, no water, no order.

> They aren't living

Comment: Congrats!! :D +1 and a check later

Comment: For the record, I liked the cringy rhymes :)